# Should model of a request for a PUT method be the same class with the model of the response of the GET method?

Tags: rest, model

In my app, the backend will use an endpoint to get and update data (with GET and PUT method). The exact same JSON schema is used for both operations. The question is, should I also use the same model for the update request body and the get response body for this or not? Can you tell me the pros and cons of either separating and combining them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should model of a request for a PUT method be the same class with the model of the response of the GET method?

See [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.4):

> A successful PUT of a given representation would suggest that a subsequent GET on that same target resource will result in an equivalent representation being sent in a 200 (OK) response.

It is normal that the PUT request will have the same [Media Type](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-3.1.1.1) as a successful GET response for that target-uri.

HTTP defines the semantics of the messages, but doesn't constrain the implementation (see [Fielding 2002](https://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-tag/2002Apr/0207.html)).

That said, if GET and PUT are using representations that change for the same reason, then a common implementation is reasonable, so it will likely be easier to maintain your code when those two paths share the same underlying model.

> what about the Single Responsibility Principle if it's the same class?

My answer is that the Single Responsibility Principle doesn't actually make your code better in this case, so you don't use it.  There are different ways you can try to generalize that idea; one is that you are working with a data structure, not an "object".  Another is that this information is crossing a boundary, and [at the boundaries, applications are not object-oriented.](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/05/31/AttheBoundaries,ApplicationsareNotObject-Oriented/)

Expressing that idea somewhat differently: what you have here is a single responsibility (manage some in memory representation of the message), but two different *roles*; an outbound role for the GET scenario (where you need to be able to convert the message into bytes, describe the content-type, and so on), and an inbound role for the PUT scenario (where you need to extract units of information from the data structure).

Comment: Sorry for the really late comment. Thanks for the answer. However, I was thinking, what about the Single Responsibility Principle if it's the same class? Because their responsibility is different. One is for the request while one is for the response.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the thorough answer.